# Вычисление кусочно заданной функции на с++

Tags: c++, c

[image: Сама система уравнений]
Вроде простая ,но есть небольшие затруднения

Не получается,пишет просто 0.8 зацикленно и все

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        float a = 0.36, b = 0.7 , c = 0.8;
        for (float x = 0; x >= 0 && x <= 10; x += 0,5)
        {
            if (x <= 5)
            {
                cout << a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c << endl;
            }
            else if (x > 5 && x <= 6)
            {
                cout << exp(x) << endl;
            }
            else if (x > 6)
            {
                cout << log(x) << endl;
            }
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы забыли написать вопрос. Но первое, что бросается в глаза - это попытка записать в целочисленный тип значение с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Числа с точкой это вещественные числа, а значит они не int, а float

Comment: На флоат исправил,но я прошу помощи . Подскажите ,как правильно написать єту систему через с++,имею лишь маленькое представление

Comment: ошибка ещё здесь `x += 0.5` - там должна быть точка, а не запятая.

Comment: Елки палки,точно. Такая глупая ошибка...Спасибо

Comment: Маленький комментарий. Это не __система__, это __кусочно заданная функция__

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        float a = 0.36, b = 0.7 , c = 0.8;
        float result;
        for (float x = 0; x >= 0 && x <= 10; x += 0.5)
        {
            if (x <= 5)
            {
                result = a * pow(x, 2) + b * x + c;
            }
            else if (x > 5 && x <= 6)
            {
                result = exp(x);
            }
            else if (x > 6)
            {
                result = log(x);
            }
            cout << result << endl;
        }
        
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]